# Show number of lower and higher values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a certain problem while trying to make an SQL. I have a table with the following format and data.

| id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 3 | 2020-06-01 |
| 12 | 4 | 2020-06-09 |
| 12 | 1 | 2020-06-20 |
| 5 | 4 | 2020-06-11 |
| 5 | 5 | 2020-06-17 |

My goal is to make something like that:

| id | lower | higher |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |

This looks for the value of the oldest row IN specific interval (ex. 100 days)and it compares it with all dates after that if their values are higher and lower and return the count.

I do have something that works but it requires more queries:
One to group take all ids with dates in the interval of xx days

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

And then I loop through each row and get its lower and higher values.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS higher, id
  FROM
    `table`
  WHERE
      id = 12 AND date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND value > (
      SELECT value FROM table 
      WHERE table.date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND id = 12 
      ORDER BY `table`.`date` ASC LIMIT 1
      )
) AS t1,(
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS deteriorated_placements
  FROM
    `table`
  WHERE
      id = 12 AND date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND value < (
      SELECT value FROM table 
      WHERE table.date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND id = 12 
      ORDER BY `table`.`date` ASC LIMIT 1
    )
) AS t2;
```

The problem with that is that I do around 40 more queries. I know it maybe is not a big issue but
Is there a way to somehow combine those 2 queries?

Comment: Can you use window functions?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, I do. I think that the given answer will help me, I just need to add a where clause and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `first_value()`:

```
select id,
       sum(value < value_1) as lower,
       sum(value > value_1) as higher
from (select t.*,
             first_value(value) over (partition by id order by date) as value_1
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: @Slavian . . . Just add a `where` clause to the subquery.  The logic doesn't really change.

Comment: The where clause needs to go in the inside query FYI.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yep, I did it I just wasn't familiar with the first_value, partition by thing as I have never used them before. Thanks a lot :D I feel utterly dumb and should focus on my SQL a lot more.